# Libuse for communication through C232HM

Tags: usb, libusb, atmega, libusb-1.0, avrdude

I have a problem with communication with Atmega644P. I am using C232HM Cable and avrdude. Unfortunately, every attempt of communication ends with the following comment from the command prompt: avrdude: Error: no libftdi or libusb support. Install libftdi1/libusb-1.0 or libftdi/libusb and run configure/make again. I installed following driver from Zadig 2.5: WinUSB (v6.1.7600.16385) and the error still occurs. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

To get past that error message, you have to do what it says: install the library that AVRDUDE needs and then build AVRDUDE from source in a way that it detects the library and uses it.  But I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do and I cannot be sure that this will ultimately work for you.  If you haven't built code from sourt before, it can be a challenge.

You never said how you installed AVRDUDE, but you might try downloading a binary version from a different place before you attempt to compile it yourself.  The Arduino IDE comes with a version of AVRDUDE, and there is also an [AVRDUDE package](https://packages.msys2.org/base/mingw-w64-avrdude) in [MSYS2](https://msys2.org) (which I contributed).